# Setting default value for QcomboBox as empty

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm on python 2.7 using pyqt 4.10, I've created a QcomboBox

```
for items in item_all:
    self.comboBox.addItem(items)
```

the `item_all` list is working perfectly  but I need it to start with the default value as Empty (note that `item_all` list is being called from a DB table so I can't have an empty value to use it)

Comment: So why not just add one before the loop?

Comment: added `self.comboBox.addItem('')` before the for loop, also added it after the for statment before `self.comboBox.addItem(items)` but both didn't change anything !

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you, the idea was the right solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a space to the `item_all` list before fetching it from the DB

```
item_all= ['',]
for items in c.fetchall():
    item_all.append(items)
self.comboBox_2.clear()
self.comboBox_2.addItems(item_all)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is `self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(-1)`. The QCombobox is blank when it is created without adding another item in the list.

Python 3.10 and PyQt6 6.5.1